# Linker imports the same symbol table for each dependent dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker

I'm building a dll that has a dependency on 2 other dlls. Everything builds successfully, with no warnings at all during the build.

However, when I dump the imports from my DLL, it shows the exact same set of symbols being imported from the 2 other DLLs (see immediately below):

```
avformat-58.dll
         1800020B0 Import Address Table
         180002390 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                      54 avformat_close_input
                      9B av_frame_copy

avutil-56.dll
         1800020B0 Import Address Table
         180002390 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                      54 avformat_close_input
                      9B av_frame_copy
```

The exports of avformat:

```
00000000 characteristics
5A2050D6 time date stamp Thu Nov 30 12:41:26 2017
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
     183 number of functions
     183 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

     ...
     ...
     83   52 000DD860 avformat_alloc_output_context2
     84   53 0016C1A0 avformat_close_input
     85   54 001609F0 avformat_configuration
     ...
     ...
```

The exports of avutil:

```
00000000 characteristics
5A2050B9 time date stamp Thu Nov 30 12:40:57 2017
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
     516 number of functions
     516 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

    ...
    ...
    154   99 00018290 av_frame_clone
    155   9A 00017A20 av_frame_copy
    156   9B 000172E0 av_frame_copy_props
    ...
    ...
```

What would cause this kind of behavior? Everything seems like it should be working.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=LinkerWeirdness.zip)'s a link to the zip file that contains my visual studio environment

Comment: Could you inspect - and perhaps paste here - the relevant portions of a /VERBOSE linker output?

Comment: Here's a dump of the seemingly relevant parts: https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=linkerVerboseOutput.txt

Comment: you can't share the browser address bar to Dropbox. You need to create a shareable link (i believe via right click)

Comment: Oh ok sorry. Try clicking [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5atdqt93dduw3g7/linkerVerboseOutput.txt?dl=0)?

Comment: Couldn't see anything useful. Could it be that one of these DLLs depends on the other?

Comment: Yes avformat depends on avutil, but I don't see that being an issue. The dlls exist together, and the imports are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently run into the same problem trying to link two different msys2-built dlls (actually their import libraries) into an MSVC application. The MS linker placed symbols from both dlls into the same IAT and pointed both dlls to it.

It seems to have been caused by the fact that object file in the two import libraries have the same names like d00000.obj, d00001.obj, etc. The solution appeared to be pretty simple: extract all files from one of the libs, rename them to have a different name prefix and create a new lib file. The problem was solved.